# Keep on refreshing the page until certain element to appear?

Tags: selenium

I have a scenario like, i want to keep on refreshing the page until some element to appear in the page. Can anyone please help me on the same?

I am using the below code for the same but the page is not refreshing after five second

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
               .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

           WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
             public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
               return driver.findElement(locator);
             }
           });
```

Thanks

Sudhansu

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [FluentWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) class.

```
   // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
   // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

In that way Selenium will just wait for a certain period of time until certain elements have been loaded.

I hope that will solve your problem so you don't have to refresh the page.

**Edited:**

As [MrTi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769273/mrti) so friendly points out, the above code will not refresh your page. It will only wait for a certain period of time until certain elements have been loaded. I just thought it might solve the problem, without you having to refresh the page. If that does not solve your problem and you still need to refresh your page, then you need to add `driver.navigate().refresh()` before the return, like this:

```
   // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
   // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       driver.navigate().refresh()
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

Comment: Emil, this code won't refresh the page.  You probably want to insert a `driver.navigate().refresh()` before the return.

Comment: Thank you @MrTi I have updated my answer with your suggestion. I hope that will solve your problem mfsi_SudhansuPanda.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you EmilC for your proposal.

It's also posible to declare the Function using java lambda's syntax the following way.

```
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(ctx.driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    wait.until((webDriver) -> {
        webDriver.navigate().refresh();
        return driver.findElement(by);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

if $all_loaded = true > do something > else > refresh page